# How to access a specific item in itemscontrol and retrieve some data in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, datatemplate

I have an `ItemsControl` with `DataTemplate` in my `Page.Xaml` and the code is like below:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="chatUI" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="340" Background="{Binding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding GridHorizontalAlign}" Margin="10,0,10,10" MinHeight="45" BorderBrush="#FF003A4F" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
                <Polygon Visibility="{Binding RightVisibility}" Fill="{Binding Background}"  Points="0,0 5,6, 0,12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-5,0" />
                <Polygon Visibility="{Binding LeftVisibility}" Fill="{Binding Background}" Points="5,0 0,6, 5,12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-5,0,0,0" />
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Time}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="LightGray" Margin="10,0,10,5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What I need right now is getting `Text` which is bound to the `TextBlock` when I right click on the grid named `myGrid`. How is that possible in C#?

Comment: Where do you need to get the bound `Text`?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I need it as a string when I right click on a specific item.

Comment: That's not the answer of my question _where_ you need the string.

Comment: but where do you want that string? in clipboard? in context menu?

Comment: @Nitin For example, in a `ContentDialog`.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg As I just mentioned, like a `ContentDialog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add the `RightTapped` event of the Grid, it will be fired when you right click the Grid.

In the `RightTapped` event we can use [`Grid.Children`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Panel_Children) to get the collection of child elements of the `Grid`. That we can get the `Grid` in the root Grid that named myGrid. That we can use the `Grid.Children` to get the `TextBlock` in the Grid.

For example:

```
private async void myGrid_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var RightTapGrid = sender as Grid;
    var childernElements = RightTapGrid.Children;
    foreach (var item in childernElements)
    {
        var grid = item as Grid;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            var itemchildernElements = grid.Children;
            foreach (var text in itemchildernElements)
            {
                var textBlock = text as TextBlock;
                var dialog = new ContentDialog()
                {
                    Title = textBlock.Text,
                    MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth 
                };
                dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "OK";
                dialog.SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel";
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you get your `Binding Data` from `Class` called `ClassName`

You can try this code

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="chatUI" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionChanged="chatUI_SelectionChanged">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="340" Background="{Binding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding GridHorizontalAlign}" Margin="10,0,10,10" MinHeight="45" BorderBrush="#FF003A4F" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
            <Polygon Visibility="{Binding RightVisibility}" Fill="{Binding Background}"  Points="0,0 5,6, 0,12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-5,0" />
            <Polygon Visibility="{Binding LeftVisibility}" Fill="{Binding Background}" Points="5,0 0,6, 5,12" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-5,0,0,0" />
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,10,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Time}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="LightGray" Margin="10,0,10,5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Listview.ItemTemplate>
```

And add SelectionChanged Event :

```
private void chatUI_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView view = (ListView)sender;
    //Get Selected Item
    ClassName class = view.SelectedItem as ClassName;
    string path = class.Text;

 // Now we have Text of selected item in Listview 

}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a ListView? Can't we do this in ItemsControl?

Comment: No , because ItemControl didn't has SelectionChanged Event